# STM32f103 HAL USB - UART bridge

Tags: usb, stm32, hal

I have a third party device that is UART programmable.

I need to create a USB - UART bridge with a functional password (programming only after entering the correct password)

generated the code using the latest version of STM32CubeMX for Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0 ...
I transfer data between USB and UART through a buffer (one for usb-uart, and another one for uart-usb)
when I try to transfer several characters everything is OK, but when I try to transfer a large data packet, problems start due to the fact that the USB speed is much higher than the UART ...

there are two questions:

1.How do I tell USB that I need to stop transferring data and wait until the UART (buffer) is busy

2.How on the side of the microcontroller to get the baud rate set on the PC (set when the terminal is connected to the virtual COM port)

Comment: Are you using the STM32 HAL drivers?

Comment: Yes... STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.8.2

Comment: It is a perfect task for the RTOS

Comment: RTOS is a valid option. Other approaches are valid as well, e.g. relying more on DMA. Example with a very small code and RAM footprint: https://github.com/manuelbl/usb-serial/firmware (it's for libopencm3, not for STM32 HAL).

Answer (score -1):

USB provides flow control. That's what you need to implement. A general introduction can be found here:

https://medium.com/@manuel.bl/usb-for-microcontrollers-part-4-handling-large-amounts-of-data-f577565c4c7d

Basically, the setup for the USB-to-UART direction should be:

1. Indicate that the code is ready to receive a USB packet
2. Receive a USB packet
3. Indicate that you are no longer ready to receive a USB packet
4. Transmit the data via UART
5. Start over

**Step 0: Initial setup**

Call `USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer` to set the buffer for receiving the USB data. Unless you use several buffers to achieve higher throughput, a single call at the start of the program is sufficient.

**Step 1: Ready to receive data**

Call `USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket`. Other than what the name implies, this function indicates that the app is ready to receive data. It immediately returns before the data has actually been received.

**Step 2: Receive a USB packet**

You don't need to do anything here. It will happen automatically. Once it's complete, `CDC_Itf_Receive` will be called.

**Step 3: Indicate that you are no longer ready to receive a USB packet**

Nothing to do here. This happens automatically whenever a packet has been received (and double buffering is not enabled).

**Step 4: Transmit the data via UART**

I guess you know how to do this. It's up to you whether you want to do it in a blocking fashion or using DMA.

Since a callback is involved, you cannot put this code into the main loop. It might be possible to put all code into `CDC_Itf_Receive` if blocking UART is used. It would appear in the order 2, 3, 4, 1. Additionally, initialization is needed (0 and 1).

In the UART-to-USB direction, you would need to implement flow control on the UART. The USB flow control is managed by the host. Even though USB is much faster than UART, flow control is relevant as the application on the host can process data as slow as it likes to.

Regarding question 2: I'm not sure I understand it... The microcontroller cannot set the baud rate on the host. Either the host can specify a baud rate (transmitted over USB and applied to UART), or if the UART has a fixed baud rate, you can ignore baud rate (any baud rate set on the host side will work as it does not apply to USB).

Comment: The most dificult and interesting part will be UART to USB ie char device to block device. You cant just send via USBchar by char as it will kill USB (especially FS) in no time, Any thoughts?

Comment: Use DMA with a ring buffer for receiving from UART and check about every 1ms for new data. Additionally, check every time a packet has been sent to the host. And if it needs to be reliable, software or hardware flow control must be used on the UART. Otherwise the ring buffer can overflow and data will be lost.

Comment: It is not as easy I afraid

Comment: Not every msek you can send something using CDC. HAL does handle it correctly.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland You can easily send something every 1ms. That's the rate at which the host polls the device.  It's the perfect rate. Of course, you need to ensure that the previous packet has been sent. -- I don't understand what you mean with "HAL does handle it correctly."

Comment: I do write USB software for STM32 for years. ***`You can easily send something every 1ms`*** this conclusion actually means EOD.